# Hot water is warm and runs out quickly

Tags: water-heater

I drained the tank and I replaced both heating elements and both thermostats.
It doesn’t fix this issue.
The water is just warm. Not hot and runs out in 10 minutes.
What’s wrong. The water heater is over 10 years old. I noticed sediment coming out when I drained it.
I recently purchased a washer, could this possibly drain the hot water by not closing off the hot water supply?

Comment: How long did you let it heat up before testing the water temperature? Washer would have no effect except when you use it on a hot or warm cycle - if it drained hot water all the time you would know it (I hope...)

Comment: It sat overnight heating up

Comment: What are the thermostats set at?  You did fill and bled the air out of the tank before turning it on?

Comment: Thermostats set originally at 125. I upped them to 135. I bled the tank using the pressure relief valve

Comment: Where are you testing the water?  Most newer houses have anti-scalding valves at sinks/tubs to prevent burning skin.  A single valve might have failed, but a few different ones should not fail at the same time.

Comment: I use the shower and the kitchen sink.

Comment: There's a line break between your washer's input water and its output water. It doesn't contain a valve that can dump water directly down the drain, so you would hear water spraying and getting pumped down the drain if the washer was the problem. Hot water tanks tend to have some kind of "vacation mode" to turn them down while you're away for long periods. Check the temperature setting. Check that the knob isn't broken, where it allows the claimed setting to differ from the actual setting.

Comment: No knob. Just a screw on the top and bottom thermostat with a temperature scale and needle on it pointing to the desired temperature.  I turned off the water at the washer. I didn’t notice anything coming out of the washer drain

Comment: With new stuff and different testing points and long enough time to get hot, the next best idea is the wiring is messed up on the thermostats/elements.  Turn off the power to the tank and post pictures of the wiring.  Is the hot water outlet pipe from the tank hot?

Comment: The pipe coming out of the tank is warm. Not hot. Should it be hot to the touch?  I can grab and hold it. Can electrical wiring issue just arise within the tank. The tank was installed in 2010 and it operated well up to now.

Comment: I am unable to post the pictures. The thermostats were wired the same was as the old ones. This was the reason I replaced the thermostats and heating elements. 
The top element is a non-simultaneous operation thermostat just like the one I replaced

Comment: Could it be the dip tube?

Comment: I have a water softener. The house was built in 1974. All soldered 1/2 soldered copper in a 3/4 PVC Pipe in a slab. 
I’ve drained the tank several times in the past couple of days and there is heavy sediment coming out of the hose. 
Could it be the sediment?  Could a slab leak cause it?  I have well water I don’t notice the well pump coming on which would be an indicator of a slab leak.

Comment: Would sediment build up be the cause

Answer (score 5):

It could be the dip tube.

The dip tube is intended to send cold water coming into the tank into the bottom of the tank, while hot water is withdrawn from the top. If the dip tube is cracked, broken or dislodged and fallen into the tank, then cold water entering the tank remains near the top of the tank and mixes with hot water, yielding just warm water.

If you remove the cold water connection, you should be able to look into the tank and see the dip tube and probe it with a piece of wire. If it is missing, cracked or short, this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: seen hot water put into the bottom of a cold tank - when water was demanded from the top - it came out hot - very hot at the temperature the hot was entering at the bottom. There was no "mixing" at all. Water is a funny thing - stratification and not mixing are normal.